# keeping checkbox unchecked/checked(according to input value) after validation fail

Tags: php, codeigniter, checkbox

I am trying to restore the value after validation if box is checked/unchecked

If I am selecting the checkbox, after validation fails it will remain checked, but when I am submitting without selecting the checkbox, it still remains checked. I want to make that unchecked instead.

```
<label>
    <span>Free Enrty:</span> 
    <input type="checkbox" name="free_check"  style="margin-top: 10px;" value="1" <?php if($_POST['free_check']==1) echo "checked='checked'"; ?>  />(Check if entry is free)
</label>
```

Comment: Did you validate your code with PHP or Javascript?

Comment: yes. when any of validation fails..

Answer (score 3):

You can use [set_checkbox](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/form_helper.html) OF CI to check.

The first parameter must contain the `name of the checkbox`, `the second parameter` must contain its value, and the `third (optional)` parameter lets you set an item as the default (use boolean TRUE/FALSE).

```
  <input type="checkbox" name="free_check" value="1" style="margin-top: 10px;" <?php echo set_checkbox('free_check', $_POST['free_check']); ?> />
```

Comment: i tried it.   but when iam subitting the form without selecting the checkbox , if validation fails i want it remain unchecked

Comment: If validation fali it will set the default value you selected while submit your form. If you want to unchecked you put the second parameter empty. Also this method only work when you use codeignitor method of validation